# Vue - Cannot redirect route to another

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to Vue and trying to redirect '/home' to '/travel', but it didn't work.

Could anyone tell me how can I do that? What is wrong with this code?

Thank You.

```
<div id="app">

<div>
  <router-link to='/home'>Home</router-link>
  <router-link to='/news'>News</router-link>
  <router-link to='/travel'>Travel</router-link>
</div>

<div>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

```
var Home = {
    template: '<h3>Home</h3>'
};

var News = {
    template: '<h3>News</h3>'
};

var Travel = {
    template: '<h3>Travel</h3>'
};

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/home', component: Home},
        { path: '/news', component: News},
        { path: '/travel', component:Travel},

        //redirect
        { path: '/home', redirect: '/travel' }
    ]
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to add a name to your routes.

```
{path: '/home',component: Home, name: 'home'}
```

and then simply use `v-bind:to` :

```
<router-link v-bind:to="{name: 'home'}">MyLink</router-link>
```

Comment: sorry, it didn't word. is this code correct?  {path:'/home',redirect:'/travel'}

Comment: With names, use `{ path: '/home', redirect: { name: 'travel' } }`.

Comment: I have tried, but it didn't work
{path: '/home',component: Home,name: 'home'},
{path: '/news',component: News,name: 'news'},
{path:'/travel',component:Travel,name: 'travel'},
 { path:'/home', redirect: { name: 'travel' } }

Comment: It didn't work is very vague,... Have you an error message ? Or on click nothing happens ? Make sur you have `v-bind:to` instead of `to`.

Comment: I haven't got any error message and sure that have 'v-bind: to'